# Is there any way to get Idle time of Redis key

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We have done all the basic crud operations so far using StackExchage.Redis  Link. We are also using wrapper of StackExchange.Redis.Extention  Link to store complex objects in Redis.

We manage User Session Token via Redis. We need to give the Session Token a sliding expiry. For that we are planning to use Session key idle time.

What is the best way to obtain Key idle time via StackExchange API [1](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) or StackExchange.Redis.Extensions API? [2](https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions)

One way is probably to execute command DEBUG OBJECT of Redis from C# client to get an idle time of particular key using the method of DebugObject. [2](https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions)

Any other better way of handling this situation or a way to execute Object command? [3](http://redis.io/commands/object)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I don't have enough rep:

IIRC, Redis keys can be written with expiration times. Why not just periodically write to the token to update the expiration time? Or, if you still need the tokens after they expire, why not just use timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

[As of StackExchange.Redis 2.0](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/449), this is now supported through the commands `KeyIdleTime` and KeyIdleTimeAsync.

Example usage can be:

```
RedisKey myKey = "my-key";
TimeSpan? idleTime = database.KeyIdleTime(myKey);
```